# How can I integrate Facebook photo album into website?

Tags: php, xml, facebook, facebook-graph-api, photos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook Api - how to access my photo album](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708423/facebook-api-how-to-access-my-photo-album)

How can I display photos from a Facebook album inside a website?

Comment: As of July of 2015, [Facebook requires authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/649907458478781/). Most of the methods listed here are now unusable. You will need to have an app and authentication to make this work. You can also use something like https://embedsocial.com/embed-gallery.php which is still working.

Comment: This tutorial works for me https://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/06/display-facebook-photos-to-your-website.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the graph api to get the images in an album, like this:
https://graph.facebook.com/ALBUM_ID/photos
You get an array containing all the images in that album. The array contains objects like this:

```
"name": "hopes you're having a great weekend!",
         "picture": "http://photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc1/5370_127826373305_40796308305_2373079_2781005_s.jpg",
         "source": "http://a4.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc1/5370_127826373305_40796308305_2373079_2781005_n.jpg",
         "height": 604,
         "width": 427,
         "images": [
            {
               "height": 604,
               "width": 427,
               "source": "http://a4.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc1/5370_127826373305_40796308305_2373079_2781005_n.jpg"
            },
            {
               "height": 254,
               "width": 180,
               "source": "http://photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc1/5370_127826373305_40796308305_2373079_2781005_a.jpg"
            },
            {
               "height": 130,
               "width": 91,
               "source": "http://photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc1/5370_127826373305_40796308305_2373079_2781005_s.jpg"
            },
            {
               "height": 106,
               "width": 75,
               "source": "http://photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc1/5370_127826373305_40796308305_2373079_2781005_t.jpg"
            }
         ],
```

This is an example from the api documentation. You can use these image links directly, facebook even gives you different sizes for the gallery. Good luck.

Comment: And yes, it is possible.

Comment: Yes i like this... But how do i get the data from this?

Comment: Well, that depends from the platform you use. The graph api call returns json. With PHP you can use json_decode, other platforms have similar libraries, please provide more information.

Comment: For anyone looking into it, if you set any kind of age restrictions on your page, you won't be able to use the plain URL.

Comment: Someone can also find handy, that you can grab list of albums instead of photos in album you already know album_ID from. Just type: https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/albums .

Comment: Does facebook have any restrictions in their T&C about this?

Comment: This is nice, but can it return thumbnails as well as full pictures?

Comment: This method was silently removed by facebook as of July 2015. You now need an access token.

Answer (score 7):

yes its possible:
Here an example with Graph:

Photos: https://graph.facebook.com/98423808305 (A photo from the Coca-Cola page)

Photo albums: https://graph.facebook.com/99394368305 (Coca-Cola's wall photos)

Answer (score 1):

If you use self hosted domain with Wordpress, you can do it with these steps:

#### Install and Activate Facebook Photo Fetcher for Wordpress

1. Download the latest version of Facebook Photo Fetcher plugin for Wordpress 
   http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-photo-fetcher/
2. Extract and activate the plugin via dashboard

#### Setting for your Facebook Photo Fetcher

1. Settings > FB Photo Fetcher
2. Click "Login to Facebook"
3. Enter your information > Login > close the popup
4. Grant Photo Permissions > Accept the permissions > Success!
5. click "Save Facebook Session"

This plugin is successfully connected with your ID Facebook account.

#### Insert your Facebook Album into Post or Page in Wordpress */

1. Search for Albums > it will open your album and get you album ID 
   For Example, the album ID is: 123456789987654321 
   Create a new post or page in wordpress > use HTML editor not visual
2. Insert this code:

   ```
   <!-- FBGallery 1234567890123456789 --> <!--/FBGallery -->
   ```

   Change 1234567890123456789 with your real facebook album ID.
3. Save > see your page.

Demo: 
http://www.justin-klein.com/projects/facebook-photo-fetcher#demo

Answer (score 0):

You will need to manage the authentication firstly. If you are using the facebook php api and its your own photo album you can request permanent access

$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' =>'user_photos friends_photos'));
}

Then after that you can make requests to the graph api such as http://graph.facebook.com/me/albums  - your auth key will at the end of that request.