# How to display my photo albums and photos that are in FB on my own website

Tags: facebook, photos

I would like to display my photo albums and photos that are in FB on my own website. However everything I have tried requires an access token that I seem to only get if I login to FB. I don't want visitors to my site to have to login to FB to see my photos.

Is there a way to get this data and not require a login? I want to pull data from my own FB account. Or is there a different way to authenticate my access behind the scenes so visitors don't have to login, to see my photos?

Comment: If you don't want your users to login, you should upload your photos on a Facebook page. You can retrieve those photos using the FB graph API without login requirement. I've found a very useful tutorial that will help you. See: https://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/06/display-facebook-photos-to-your-website.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Facebook has recently launched a way to share the album with public without having to Signin. Every album will have link below this key word **Share this album with anyone by sending them this public link**. Take a look at this [HOW TO](http://www.guidingtech.com/5443/share-facebook-photo-album-public-link/) for more information.

EDIT: However, for embedding refer this SO which explains how to grant [permanent access to your photo albums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829477/how-can-i-intergrate-facebook-photo-album-into-website/5829659#5829659)

Another option is using 8 photo restricted [Facebook Photo Badge](https://www.facebook.com/badges/photo.php?creating)

[Showzey](http://www.showzey.com/) seems to be working on liberating your photos and provides widgets.

Comment: i got the library files from https://github.com/facebook/connect-js. Still I cannot get the Albums and Photos from the facebook to display it in my website.. I want to photo and comment of the currectly logged in user of the facebook. I need to Do The same functionaliy described in the following link. http://flavors.me/websolusionz . If You see this page then you can find how the photos and comments are displayed.

Comment: The how to link is broken for me.

Comment: Facebook Badge will restrict you to 8 photos. You can try the [Famax plugin](http://www.codehandling.com/2015/03/famax-40-complete-facebook-fanpage.html) to embed all Albums and Photos etc. on your website.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook has a [badges page](https://www.facebook.com/badges/) that has different options for embedding Facebook content onto your site. The [photo badge](https://www.facebook.com/badges/photo.php?creating) should fit your criteria.

Comment: Photo Badge would restrict you to 8 photos.

Comment: Yes - that is Facebook's limitation. Otherwise you are better off posting photos to a different site like Picasa or Flickr to embed them.

Comment: i want to show the face book photo for the session user, like the functionality in the  following link. http://flavors.me/websolusionz#e23/facebook2

Answer (score 2):

May be [this method](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/06/display-facebook-photos-to-your-website.html) could help you guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it through a public fan page or a business page.

I put this script together a while back: http://roughgiraffed.com/FBalbum/.    Working on a more legit version - will post when complete.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine galleria (open source javascript image gallery framework) with a plug-in to integrate with facebook.

You can find the links bellow:

http://galleria.io/

http://www.alexanderinteractive.com/blog/2012/03/display-facebook-photos-on-your-website-with-galleria/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this very nice [plugin](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/facebook-display/18079) for Joomla. Take a look.