# Connect to only my Facebook account and show my photos on my Website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to show my albums from Facebook on my website using Graph API or FQL, but all the examples I find are to access the photo albums of my visitors.

Can anyone guide me in how to connect to my Facebook account and check my albums for visitors to my site to see my photos?

Comment: This was asked previously. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945720/how-to-display-my-photo-albums-and-photos-that-are-in-fb-on-my-own-website

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to feed you the codes, but what you should do is, run the Oauth script at backend where user has no access to, get the accesstoken which is then used for the main site to fetch the required details.

It is inshort hardcoding (or accessing from a db/file) the access_token instead of generating it by authorizing the visitor which shows their details.

Once you have the image links, you only have to update the new ones. You should code the site such a way to avoid unwanted queries.