# Making a facebook album slideshow with php, html? jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Hello I'm making a website, and I want the albums and photos from a facebook page to be shown in a box.

Here is an example
I want the albums and photos to be shown just like this, in a slide, instead of finding the  it automatically takes the photos from any decided album.
[Example page](http://iseeit.no/page/drommeplassen/slideshow/index.php)

Here is the code used in the example page, this takes random pictures stored in a folder and displays them, same method should be used for the facebook album. This is where I'm stuck.

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>*title*</title>

<script src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.cycle.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myslides').cycle({
    fit: 1, pause: 2, timeout: 200
});
});
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/dynamicslides.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>

<?php
$directory = 'images/slideshow/';   
try {       
// Styling for images   
echo "<div id=\"myslides\">";   
foreach ( new DirectoryIterator($directory) as $item ) {            
    if ($item->isFile()) {
        $path = $directory . "/" . $item;   
        echo "<img src=\"" . $path . "\" />";   
    }
}   
echo "</div>";
}   
catch(Exception $e) {
echo 'No images found for this slideshow.<br />';   
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope you understand what I'm trying to say here :)

I have little knowledge about this, so be easy one me.
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Where are you having problems exactly? Why do you want to do it yourself when there are literally hundreds of ready-made solutions?

Comment: I've been trying to search around the web, haven't stumbled upon anything that I could use, seems like you have though, if there already are good enough templates that I can use then lead the way :)

Comment: Look for pagination scripts in for example PHP or Javascript (with jQuery). Other than that, all you need to do, is fetch all images from a certain FB page.

Answer (score 0):

From what i have understood

Give a name tag to each of the photos in an album.. when u click on one album all you need to do is run the a loop for that name tag.

If this doesn't suffice, explain your problem clearly.  Some code will actually help understand the problem better

Comment: Changed the whole topic, hope it makes more sense now :)

Comment: I still am not clear of what you want.. if you are trying to fetch the images of Facebook just use the api .. It is already explained here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829477/how-can-i-integrate-facebook-photo-album-into-website

if you are trying to make use of jquery cycle , the following example can be used : http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/begin.html


but if you are trying to get all the Facebook photos and then using it .. you can prefetch all the images using javascript and once its done u can add it to your#myslides in your example